# Why does angular.io certificate is valid?

Tags: ssl, https

Im having issues with angular.io in my enterprise network caused by the certificate. Looking more in detail I noticed its been signed for *.firebaseapp.com. However it looks valid in my phone. [Android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b622v.jpg)
It doesnt make any sense, you cant have a valid ssl connection if the certificate was signed for another domain. Does anoyone understand whats happening with that certificate and why its look valid for my android browsers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the certificate details all look at the long list of Subject Alternative Names you will see that *.angular.io is covered under there. You can read more about those [here](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm).

Basically, it's just a list of hostnames that can used with one certificate.

[image: screenshot of certificate details].